# %run vs. copy/paste discrepancy in function containing global commands in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Below is an import function for reading in a .csv file into python. I use the global command to create a global variable "data" and read the .csv file into the "data" variable for the user to use.

If I copy/paste the code into my client, it works just fine. However, when I "read" the file containing the code in with %run, the function will run but the "data" global variable won't be created (e.g., I call "data", and get an error).

Note: I know this code isn't polished yet, but I'm not sure why I'm having the problem I'm having.

```
def dat():
import pandas as pd
file = raw_input('Enter your .csv file:  ')
global data
try:
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    print "\nI've created the following variables for you: 'data' will contain your datafile that we just imported."
except:
    print "I'm so sorry, but I have no idea what just went wrong."
```

some of the data in the .csv file look like this:

```
Les1    Les2    Les3
2   4   4
3   3   3
1   5   3
2   4   3
```

Comment: Can you paste few lines of your `.csv` file so we can replicate your problem?

Comment: Does that help? I edited the above question to show some of the data. I can also provide some of the data if you need.

Comment: Here is a sample of the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cm8fsxnn7w55zlq/survey_sample.csv?dl=0

Comment: What do you mean by `%run`? When you try to run the file from `IPython` shell?

Comment: Yes and no, I'm working through Canopy. When I try to run the file with %run (or by just selecting the file from a drop down menu), the function has the problem I described.

Comment: It work fine for me.

Comment: Do you think it could be a problem with my IDE?

Comment: Is it working for you now?

Comment: I'm realizing it only doesn't work when I use the Canopy IDE, so lesson learned =D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**test.csv**

```
Les1,Les2,Les3
2,4,4
3,3,3
1,5,3
2,4,3
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd

def dat():
    file = raw_input('Enter your .csv file:  ')
    global data
    try:
        data = pd.read_csv(file)
        print data
        print "\nI've created the following variables for you: 'data' will contain your datafile that we just imported."
    except:
        print "I'm so sorry, but I have no idea what just went wrong."

dat()
```

Output:

```
Enter your .csv file:  test.csv
   Les1  Les2  Les3
0     2     4     4
1     3     3     3
2     1     5     3
3     2     4     3

I've created the following variables for you: 'data' will contain your datafile that we just imported.
```